# Android: How to fill GridView programatically before starting transition?

Tags: android, android-gridview, pending-transition

I have an `MainActivity A`, from which the user can select different items which are displayed in `Activity B` in a `GridView`. Between those Activities I have a Sliding-Transistion (`Activity A` slides out to the left, `Activity B slides in from right`)

My problem is, that if the animation starts, `Activity B` screen is not created complete (GridView items are added programmatically), so I see an empty screen sliding in from the right, which looks dump.

So my question: **Is it possible to create/load `Activity B` *before* transition starts?**

[image]

I attach some code, but all is pretty straight forward. Only the grid items consists of images with different states...

Activity A: start Intent (as usual)

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, SoundShareActivity.class);
 //...
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
 overridePendingTransition(anim.slide_in_from_right_to_left,
            anim.slide_out_to_left); 
 //anim defined in xml
```

Activity B: onCreate

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 //...
 mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view_sounds);
 mAdapter = new SoundAdapter(getApplicationContext(), THE_DATA);
 mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 mGridView.setOnItemClickListener( ... );
 mGridView.setLongClickable(true);
 mGridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(...);
```

Comment: Not sure about how this would work with Activities, but you could look into implementing this with Fragments.

Comment: As pointed by others why dont you use fragments? Are you performing lot of operations in adapter.getView(...)? And, are you sure about that New_Task intent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Replace your activity to FragmentActivity
2. implement GridView and set the adapter in the fragment constructor/onCreateView functions
3. Replace Fragment with FragmentTransaction setCustomAnimations function.

very simple to implement

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible using activities because you can't assign content to a `View` until it'll be inflated, which happens by `setContentView()` in Activity, usually in `OnCreate()`: so `Activity` has to be started first. But, since only one `Activity` instance could be active at one time, you can't do it while you are inside your first `Activity`.

Workaroud: use `Fragment`s. You can have many instances of Fragments at one time, therefore, you can show to the user, for example, `Fragment1` while loading `Fragment2`. [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) is often used in conjuction with fragments and it loads three pages by default, which means that while you see a page in `ViewPager`, previous and next pages and corresponding fragments are actually being loading or already loaded. You can use similar technique for your task.